# php form submitted automatically

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello I have a page index.php with a contact form in it, the problem is that when I load the page it's like I pressed the submit button and I don't know why.. I want that the alert of success or error only appear after pressing the submit button not any time the page load.. here is the code:

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"]){//form was submitted

    if($_POST['email'] != "" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error .= '<br /><strong>Incorrect Email Address</strong>';
    }
}else{
    $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Form Not Submitted</strong></div>';
}

if($error)
    $result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There was some error(s) in the form: </strong>'.$error.'</div>';
else {
    if(mail("carlosd.dev@gmail.com",$_POST['subject'],"
         Name: ".$_POST['name']."
         Email: ".$_POST['email']."
         Message: ".$_POST['message'])){
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Form Submitted We Will Be In Touch Soon!</div>';
    }else{
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry the form was not submitted, please try again</div>';
    }

}?>
```

and right above this I have my HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP | Practicas</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="emailForm">

                <h2>Contact Form<br /></h2>
                <form action="index.php" method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Your name: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required="true" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Your email: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required="true"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject of message" required="true" value="<?php echo $_POST['subject']; ?>"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the message" required="true"><?php echo $_POST['message']; ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Send!" />

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
 </head>
```

what can I do to solve this??

Comment: Your brace for the submit is in the wrong spot. Plus, you need to use `isset()` for `if($_POST["submit"]){`

Answer (score 0):

put your **PHP** code on top and your **HTML** form on bottom
change this

```
if($_POST["submit"]){//form was submitted
```

with this

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){//form was submitted
```

**also change this**

```
if($_POST['email'] != "" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
```

**with this**

```
if(!empty($_POST['email']) AND !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
```

**also change the "error" check**

```
if($error)
```

**with**

```
if(strlen($error)>0) {
```

and your else should be

```
{ else
```

ALL Code

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){//form was submitted
        if(!empty($_POST['email']) AND !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $error .= '<br /><strong>Incorrect Email Address</strong>';
        }
    } else {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Form Not Submitted</strong></div>';
    }
    if(strlen($error)>0) {
        $result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There was some error(s) in the form: </strong>'.$error.'</div>';
    } else {
        if(mail("carlosd.dev@gmail.com",$_POST['subject'],"
             Name: ".$_POST['name']."
             Email: ".$_POST['email']."
             Message: ".$_POST['message'])){
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Form Submitted We Will Be In Touch Soon!</div>';
        } else {
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry the form was not submitted, please try again</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `&& !empty($_POST["submit"])` that's not needed. It's not an input where a user inputs data, so it will always be "not empty". `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` will suffice. The OP's brace for it is in the wrong spot.

Comment: @Fred-ii- :) you are right, this was a long night :) tired eyes

Comment: I know the feeling all too well Peter.

Comment: Hi! thanks for reply, i edited the line to isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"])  but still when i load the page the email is send even if i don't press the send button

Comment: In the first `}else{` the first brace for it `}` needs to be moved just before the `?>` tag. The condition needs to wrap the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Also check this

add to HTML form

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true">
```

PHP check if form submitted

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']=='true') {
//true
} esle {
//false
}
?>
```

This will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Your page is one self-calling element. What's happening is on first load it's trying to find the `email` and other inputs in `$_POST` array. Which naturally isn't there, hence the alert.
Use `<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>'' method="post">` instead of 
`<form action="index.php" method="post">`. This will most likely solve the problem.
**An off-topic suggestion:** Use `filter_input(INPUT_POST,'submit')` instead of `$_POST['index']`. It's safer and is recommended.

**Your Code seems to have lots of bugs when ran in my machine(WAMP Server). Initialize `$error` and `$result` variables. That seems to help.**

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, i solved the problem is working fine now can you tell me how to clean the inputs after a success submited form??

Comment: You may try putting every form-filling element under `if( !isset($_POST) ) { //Echo form fill element}`. This way the sticky form structure remains, and repeated fiilling will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//here your code

}
```

Comment: Please add some  explanation to make it more useful for readers.